# How to Search Comma Separated Strings or List in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I have a column in a Django Model Where the text is separated by Commas or the list of user ids.

I used this column to search the number of occurrences this user's id is linked in newly registered users.

`[17, 3, 1]`

in DB it is saved like this separated by commas.

When I used the

`MyModel.objects.filter(column__contains="7".count()`

when tried with other options like iregex, iexact, icontains or exact nothing shows.

It includes the 7 from 17 and fetches the result.

Is there any efficient solution for this problem?

Comment: try using the regex search `\b7\b`

Comment: yes, this one works. Thanks